# Three20: TTTableViewController, UITabBar and autoresizesForKeyboard create gap

Tags: ios, keyboard, three20, uitableview

When I have a UITabBar with a TTTableViewController and a autoresizesForKeyboard set to YES, there's a gap in the height of the Tab Bar (probably) above the keyboard.

How could this be fixed?

[image: Gap between the keyboard and the table view]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into the same problem and found a solution.  If you're using a modal view you can call self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES; and you won't see any difference as it's covering up the tab bar anyway but when the keyboard appears the gap is gone :)

Comment: Thanks! It solved the gap. And it works also on pushed view controllers, not only modals. But what if I do need the bottom bar to stay (in my case it's not necessary, but it's goot to know)

Comment: Yeah I only said modals because usually if the tab bar shows you want it to show. I've also got a view with this issue and I've been trying to figure out another solution as well. I'll let you know if/when I find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's a pull request that fixes this issue:
https://github.com/facebook/three20/pull/486

I've used the fix in an app and it works perfectly for me.